# C: Stack implementation

Tags: c, stack, runtime-error

following code for stack implementation, produces runtime-errors, although it does compile .. Can anyone help me identify find the error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 5
```

// declared a structure for stack which has an int array and top as it's members..

```
struct stack{
   int a[size],top;
}s;
```

// following method pushes element 'item' in stack when called after checking if stack-overflows or not?

```
void push(int item){
if(s.top >= size-1)
    printf("\nStack overflow..\n");
else
    s.a[++s.top] = item;
}
```

following method pops one element when called..

```
int pop(){
if(s.top == -1){
    printf("\n..Stack underflow..\n");
    return 0;
}
return s.a[s.top];
}
```

// displays elements in the stack till a[top]

```
void display(){
int i;
for(i = s.top; i>=0; i--){
    printf("\n%d", &s.a[i]);
}
}
```

// main() method..

```
int main(){
s.top = -1;
int item, choice;
char ans;

printf("  ..Stack Implementation..\n");
printf("-----------------------------");
do{
    printf("\nMain Menu");
    printf("\n-------------");
    printf("\n     1. Push\n     2. Pop\n     3. Display\n     4. Exit\n");
    printf("\n  Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", choice);

    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        printf("\nEnter item to be pushed:  ");
        scanf("%d", &item);
        push(item);
        break;
    case 2:
        pop();
        break;
    case 3:
        display();
        break;
    case 4:
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\n Want to continue? :");
    scanf("%c", &ans);
}while(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `produces runtime-error` can you please elaborate?

Comment: Why does push pre-increment top? You'll never store anything in space 0. Pop doesn't decrement top. Also I think you're using `[5]` - you can't, only 0-4 are valid.

Comment: it produces o/p till displaying "Enter your choice", then there is some problem ..

Comment: Build a debug version (if you're building with GCC/Clang add the `-g` option) and run in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine and even walk up the function call stack. When walking up to your code, you can examine the values of variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small typo [I think so, as your other occurrences are correct]. Change

```
scanf("%d", choice);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

Also, there is a small problem in `scanf("%c", &ans);`. It will suffer from the previously-pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>. Use

```
scanf(" %c", &ans);  //mind the space before %
```

---

Other Issues: [Added after the edit]

1. `printf("\n%d", &s.a[i]);` -- get rid of the `&`, don't need that in `printf()`
2. `return s.a[s.top];` should be `return s.a[s.top--];`

Comment: @JainamJhaveri `halts`? how's so?

Comment: i forgot "&" and all the problems resulted due to that.

Comment: @JainamJhaveri ,Since you've edited the `&` into your code, this answer's first part doesn't make any sense. Please don't make such edits. Revert them

Comment: ill take care next time ;) @CoolGuy